# Threejs: How to dynamically change width and height of plane?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to easily change width and height of plane dynamically? The code below has no effect.

```
plane.geometry.parameters.width = width;
plane.geometry.parameters.height = height;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create the plane mesh

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1 );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

You can then dynamically change the dimensions by resetting the scale, like so:

```
mesh.scale.set( width, height, 1 );
```

three.js r.74

Comment: so, is this changing actual width & height, or is it just scaling. is scaling the same as changing dimensions? because wouldn't mesh.scale.set multiply whatever dims the plane had with the width value? unless of course if the plane had 1 as width.

Comment: The size in local coordinate space is not changed. The size in world space is changed. That is the purpose of the `mesh.matrix` transform.

Comment: Is there a way to change the width and height using the same width and height units though? Because from my experimentation scale has a completely different set of units since 1 scale unit is 100% the default size. I would like to be able to input the same units into the plane Geometry and then the "scale" after.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. You can try:

```
mesh.geometry.width = width;
mesh.updateMatrix();
```