# why three.js updates geometry only when new geometry is defined?

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I have a question about updating geometry in three.js using dat.gui.

I expected I could update the geometry by updating the value tied into the geometry by object as below.

```
gui.add(parameter, 'width')
    .min(1)
    .max(10)
    .step(0.1)
    .name('cubeWidth')
    .onChange((value) => {
        mesh.geometry.dispose();

        geometry.parameters.width = parameter.width
        console.log(mesh)

    })
```

However, it updates the geometry only when I redefine the geometry like below.

```
mesh.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(parameter.width, 1, 1);
```

It's bit weird to me because even when I log the geometry data both shows the updated width value like below.
[image]

Why does only the first approach work while the other one not work?

Comment: It's better to do this, instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850419/threejs-how-to-dynamically-change-width-and-height-of-plane/35854276#35854276

Comment: @WestLangley I used the approach before but just wanted to figure out another way of changing shape. cause changing scale works for some cases not all the cases. isn't it?

Comment: It works for the case you presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> geometry.parameters.width = parameter.width

This has no effect. Parameters are only processed when a geometry is created. The `parameters` property is in fact read-only.

The solution for your issue is indeed to recreate the geometry with the new set of parameters.