# Three.js - Inconsistency in updating plane size after its created has me confused

Tags: three.js

I'm setting the height and width to 100 when setting the `PlaneGemoetry`. Then I am scaling to the exact same size later using `plane.scale(100, 100, 1);`. But the scaled plane is much bigger. Why is the exact same dimensions so different? Am I doing something wrong, or is the scale values really completely different?

My expectation is that when I set the scale to 100, 100 it should not change size because that's the same size I created it at.

```js
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 2, 2 ); //<--- sets scale here
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
plane.scale.set( 100, 100, 1 ); //< -- why does 100, 100 suddenly turn into a completely
```

Here's a codepen for the issue:
https://codepen.io/carelesscourage/pen/zYLbZBv

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling is multiplicative. So your original size * scale is the equivalent of doing

```
100 * 100 = 10000
```

You’re getting a plane that’s ten thousand units wide. If you want to return to its initial size, just set the scale to 1, since 100 * 1 = 100

Comment: Maybe my mistake is using scaling then. Is there another way to change height and width of the plane after its made? Its very important for my usecase that I should be able to use the same size units when updating the size.

Comment: I got this solution from this stackoverflow answer. But if youre right then isnt this accepted answer actually wrong? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850419/threejs-how-to-dynamically-change-width-and-height-of-plane

Comment: Both answers are right for their respective questions.

Comment: I dont think I agree with that at all. Their question is explicitly how to change with and height using a width and height value. If scale just scales like you described then it doesnt answer the question because in that case its impossible to use scale to set width and height using width and height values. Which is also what im asking for

Comment: The other answer suggests you start the initial geometry values to 1: `THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1)`. You’re starting with `(100, 100)`, so your results are showing up 100x larger. Try initiating your geometry with 1.

Comment: Wait, that might actually work now that I think about it. Ill try it out when I get home and accept your answer as the correct one if it works out.